# Date conversion from db to display

Tags: php, datetime, date

I'm reading a datetime field from mysql db. I'd like to convert it in PHP:

from: `2009-05-23 14:46:23`

to `05/23/2009 02:46 pm`

Notice the `am/pm` conversion.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Yes, I'm going the conversion in PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// assume you retrieve the mysql date in variable $date
date("m/d/Y h:i a", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Note that if the sql layer already returns a DateTime object, you'd do something similar with the `date_format()` function.

Comment: @cballou, Thanks man for your help, and for getting right to the point ;)

Answer (score 0):

Call me old fashioned.  I store all dates as epoch, and if I will ever go outside my timezone, as epoch of UTC of the date.

Epoch is seconds since Jan 1st, 1970 or something like that.

Known in MySQL as Unixtime.  FROM_UNIXTIME(), etc..

```
$epoch = strtotime($mdate);
```

You can also store dates directly in MySQL with data type DATETIME if you are so inclined.
Your chosen format is a drop in replacement actually.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type that's return by your db code, you can create a new DateTime object or format an existing one with `date_format()`. From the example you give, the date format string should be `"m/d/Y h:i a"`. Note that the conversion from 24h to 12h is handled in either case.

Have a look at the format options for [`DateTime:date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [`DateTime:format()` (date_format is an alias for this)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)